# How to merge cell in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table and want to merge cell of specific cells based on their number inside. It likes remove divider border.

it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sJ9O.png

I tried with className in `Columns` by using `border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;` and `border-top: 1px solid transparent !important;` , but it did not work.
Could you tell me how to do that?
Thanks you.

Comment: Hung Vu, have you get solution for this?

Comment: @Hung Vu, any updates?

Comment: use defaultColumn in useTable, and then you can pass cell : customTableCell
For example:

```
  const defaultColumn = useMemo(
    () => ({
      Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
      Cell: customTableCell || TableCell,
      Header: DefaultHeader,
    }),
    []
  );


const instance = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data: data || [zeroStateData],
      defaultColumn,
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use defaultColumn in useTable, and then you can pass cell : customTableCell For example:

```js
const defaultColumn = useMemo( () => ({ 
Filter: DefaultColumnFilter, 
Cell: customTableCell || TableCell, 
Header: DefaultHeader, }), [] );
```

```js
const instance = useTable( {
 columns, data: data || [zeroStateData], 
defaultColumn, }, );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the built-in table attribute called colSpan which specifies how many cells you are merging horizontally.

```
<TableCell colSpan=2> My Cell </TableCell>
```